# Unable to connect any bluetooth devices, but devices found

Tags: bluetooth, 19.10, iwlwifi, bluez

Kernel version: 5.0.0-37-generic.

Using a wifi/ bluetooth intel card. Firmware is installed. Wifi is working probably. Rfkill is unblocked. I am very new to linux, and have read many similar questions. Not sure if I did wrong or it's a bug.

```
tommy@tommy-desktop:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
24:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
tommy@tommy-desktop:~$ find /lib/firmware -name "*3168*"
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3168-21.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3168-27.ucode
```

Try pairing with bluetoothctl.

```
root@tommy-desktop:~# bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller 48:F1:7F:8E:CA:FF tommy-desktop [default]
[NEW] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D [TV] Samsung Q60 Series (55)
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# devices 
Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D [TV] Samsung Q60 Series (55)
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 48:F1:7F:8E:CA:FF Discovering: yes
[CHG] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D RSSI: -57
[bluetooth]# pairable on
Changing pairable on succeeded
[CHG] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D ManufacturerData Key: 0x0075
[CHG] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D ManufacturerData Value:
  42 04 01 20 6e 19 0d 00 02 01 37 01 01 00 01 00  B.. n.....7.....
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          ........        
[CHG] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D ManufacturerData Key: 0x001d
[CHG] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D ManufacturerData Value:
  00 01 4c                                         ..L             
[NEW] Device D0:27:9D:F8:3C:06 HORI Wireless Controller Light
[CHG] Device D0:27:9D:F8:3C:06 RSSI: -42
[bluetooth]# pair D0:27:9D:F8:3C:06 
Attempting to pair with D0:27:9D:F8:3C:06
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists
[CHG] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D ManufacturerData Key: 0x0075
[CHG] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D ManufacturerData Value:
  42 04 01 01 6e 24 fc e5 c1 1b 7d 26 fc e5 c1 1b  B...n$....}&....
  7c 01 00 00 00 00 00 00                          |.......        
[CHG] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D ManufacturerData Key: 0x001d
[CHG] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D ManufacturerData Value:
  00 01 4c                                         ..L             
[CHG] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D ManufacturerData Key: 0x0075
[CHG] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D ManufacturerData Value:
  42 04 01 20 6e 19 0d 00 02 01 37 01 01 00 01 00  B.. n.....7.....
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          ........        
[CHG] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D ManufacturerData Key: 0x001d
[CHG] Device 24:FC:E5:C1:1B:7D ManufacturerData Value:
  00 01 4c                                         ..L             
[bluetooth]# paired-devices 
[bluetooth]# help 
Menu main:
Available commands:
```

Bluetooth service status.

```
tommy@tommy-desktop:~$ systemctl status bluetooth.service 
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-12-21 16:42:15 HKT; 1h 8min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1016 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1016 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 21 16:42:35 tommy-desktop bluetoothd[1016]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.92 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Dec 21 16:42:35 tommy-desktop bluetoothd[1016]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.92 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Dec 21 17:14:41 tommy-desktop bluetoothd[1016]: Failed to disconnect device: Not Powered (0x0f)
Dec 21 17:14:41 tommy-desktop bluetoothd[1016]: Failed to disconnect device: Not Powered (0x0f)
Dec 21 17:28:43 tommy-desktop bluetoothd[1016]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.92 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Dec 21 17:28:43 tommy-desktop bluetoothd[1016]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.92 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Dec 21 17:28:48 tommy-desktop bluetoothd[1016]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.181 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Dec 21 17:28:48 tommy-desktop bluetoothd[1016]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.181 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Dec 21 17:34:46 tommy-desktop bluetoothd[1016]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Dec 21 17:38:59 tommy-desktop bluetoothd[1016]: D0:27:9D:F8:3C:06: error updating services: Device or resource busy (16)
```

Dmesg | grep blue

```
tommy@tommy-desktop:~$ dmesg | grep Blue
[    4.580923] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.580935] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.580939] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.580940] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.580943] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.606559] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810225019140f34
[    4.606560] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 34
[    5.384883] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.384884] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.384887] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   25.468251] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   25.468261] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   25.468269] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1934.544470] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
[ 1934.548506] Bluetooth: hci0: failed to disable LE scan: status 0x1f
[ 1943.088744] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x041f tx timeout
[ 1945.104357] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0406 tx timeout
[ 2973.636896] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
[ 2973.636899] Bluetooth: hci0: failed to disable LE scan: status 0x1f
[ 3155.778116] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c1a tx timeout
tommy@tommy-desktop:~$ sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197423/bluetooth-not-seeing-devices-on-dell-inspiron-3793-in-ubuntu-19-10/1197549#1197549

Comment: It didn't, I have already turn "everthing" on in bluetoothctl, but no luck. Sometimes it'll log paired, But the paring devices are still stuck in pairing mode, and not working. Except for the gamepad, I also tried on a bluetooth soundcard. PulseAudio and pulseaudio-module bluetooth are also installed.